# "Watch for hidden gems" - What does this mean in the reviews?

Tags: support

I was reviewing a user's first answer today, and that was when I noticed this line:

> This is a new user's answer to an old question. Watch for hidden gems,
>   non-answers, and spam.

What does the `hidden gem` mean?

[image: Spooky hidden gem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*Hidden gems* is an idiom which means something which is extremely outstanding and not many people may know about"

See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237652/whats-an-alternative-for-hidden-gem

Comment: Frankly, for a moment I thought they are referring to some sort of hidden script, since this is a programming community :)

Comment: @JackJohansson It could refer to both so that's probably a valid point.